# Enable users to POST directly to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

[This process](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload) allows users to upload (POST) data directly to a specified GCS bucket, without any GAE intermediation. For large files, this seems  easier/faster/better for both users and devs. Is it possible to do something like this using the Google Cloud's Python SDK (or pure Python)?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow users to upload directly from the web browser by using the Cloud Storage XML API. The example below uploads to a **public** bucket, naming the file with what the user inputs in the "key" text field:

```
<form action="http://storage-upload.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="key" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://www.example.com/success_notification.html">

    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

There are multiple ways to secure this, the [POST Object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object) documentation provides an example of how to do it with a Policy Document generated with Python, but you could also use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which can be generated with the [App Identity Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/).

Another interesting thing about the Cloud Storage XML API, is that it also allows you to implement [Resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload), which might be the best approach for uploading large files.

About the size limit, I could not find any information in the Official Docs about a limit for this API in specific, but I figure this could be easily determined by running some tests.